# Jasper Reports taking long time in Server Aplicattion, But not in localhost

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a web application in glassfish , mounted virtual server windows server 2012 and the application have a report made in Jaspersoft studio which brings me some records with pictures , when I run it on my local server delay between 30 to 40 seconds, but when I run from the virtual server remotely , the same report with the same amount of data (500 records) delay between 8 to 9 minutes , but only happens when running remotely, because to run it locally directly on the server remote virtual desktop , also delay between 30 to 40 seconds.

specification server:

- windows server 2012 R2
- 2 GB RAM
- Upload speed: 80Mbps - Download speed: 42Mbps
- 512 mb of memory for JAVA

this is the code:

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    Conexion conexion = null;
    try{
        conexion = new Conexion();
        conexion.setConectar(true);
        System.out.println("Seguimiento [Inicio] "+(new Date()).toString());
        try {
            String directorio;
            String piepagina;
            ConsultarGenerales generales = new ConsultarGenerales();
            generales.setConexion(conexion);
            SortedMap[] s = generales.getGenerales();

            ConsultarAccesorios consultar = new ConsultarAccesorios(); 
            consultar.setParametros(request);
            /*ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(consultar.getEquiposQuery());
            JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet);*/


            directorio = "";
            piepagina = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                directorio = s[i].get("ruta_reportes").toString();
                piepagina = s[i].get("pie_reportes").toString();
            }

            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("Solicitante",Utils.vton(request.getParameter("solicitante")));
            parameters.put("Generador",Utils.vton(request.getParameter("generador")));
            parameters.put("Observaciones",Utils.vton(request.getParameter("observaciones")));
            parameters.put("PiePagina",piepagina.replace('\\', '/'));
            parameters.put("Directorio",directorio.replace('\\', '/'));
            /*
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(directorio+"ReporteEquipos1.jasper"); 
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis); 
            JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(bufferedInputStream); 

            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("F:\\Desarrollo\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\Eidyhealth\\Prenatal\\HistoriaClinica1.jrxml");
            */
            System.out.println("Seguimiento [Load] "+(new Date()).toString());
            JasperDesign jDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(directorio+"ReporteAccesoriosV2.jrxml");
            JRDesignQuery queryAcc = new JRDesignQuery();
            queryAcc.setText(consultar.getAccesoriosQuery());
            jDesign.setQuery(queryAcc);

            System.out.println("Seguimiento [Compilar] "+(new Date()).toString());
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jDesign);

            System.out.println("Seguimiento [Llenar] "+(new Date()).toString());

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, conexion.getConexion());

            /*JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, resultSetDataSource);*/

            // Exporta el informe a PDF
            System.out.println("Seguimiento [Pdf] "+(new Date()).toString());
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print,response.getOutputStream());
            /*fis.close();*/
            System.out.println("Seguimiento [Fin] "+(new Date()).toString());
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          finally {
            conexion.setCerrarConexion(true);
          }

        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(conexion != null){
            try {
                conexion.setCerrarConexion(true);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide more information about the hardware you are using as well as backend infrastructure. Just looking at your code is not going to help.